# How to Open Drop down (combo items) of Combo Box on KeyDown Event?

Tags: c#, events, combobox, onclick, keydown

**Scenario** :
I am working on project where my client needs **to open the drop down(combo items) of combo box on f1 key down**, but i am achieving it my try multiple codes.
**how can i open combo box items on any key event.**
Here is my code

```
private void dgvItemLists_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Subtract)
                {
                    txtDiscount.Focus();
                }

                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Add)
                {
                    mtxtQty.Focus();
                }

                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F1)
                {
                   cmbAreaName.Focus();
                //  cmbAreaName.AllowDrop = true;
               //   cmbAreaName.Show();
                  cmbAreaName_Click(this, new System.EventArgs());
                  //cmbAreaName_DrawItem(this, new DrawItemEventArgs);

                 // cmbAreaName.SelectedIndexChanged=;
                }

}
```

required result image is given.

[image]

any suggestions or recommendations of code will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you're just executing the code inside the `Click` event when you call `cmbAreaName_Click`.

If you want to show the dropdown, set the `DroppedDown` property to `true`:

```
cmbAreaName.DroppedDown = true;
```

Comment: it worked for me and to move in combo i also put cmbAreaName.focus(); in my code.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F1)
{
    cmbAreaName.DroppedDown = true;
}
```

Maybe you should put this in a method so you can raise it on events you need.

Comment: right,to change the focus of control to combo i also put cmbAreaName.focus(); in my code.